# How can we get Jmeter results in non-GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter

How can we get the HTTP request response values **maximum time**, **minumum time** and **average time** in the JMeter non-GUI mode?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to specify the output file. As per section [2.4.4 Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

> -l
>
> name of JTL file to log sample results to].

So you can [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
```

After test finishes all the metrics will be stored in `results.jtl` file, which is basically a CSV file and you will be able to:

1. Calculate min/max/average using Excel or equivalent
2. Open .jtl file with the listener of your choice, i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and view the values.

Also check out [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) just in case

Answer (score 2):

You can get even more than what Dmitri describes using JMeter 3.0 and the feature called Dashboard report.

Read this documentation which explain how to output the report at end of load test or using an existing CSV file:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html