# How will I know how many API requests are failed and passed when I am using the Jmeter in Non-GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am a beginner to Jmeter.My goal is to test the performance of 1000000 API requests.I have started testing in GUI mode but after reaching 5000 requests it's throwing an error.From that error I noticed that I have to run the Jmeter in Non-GUI mode to run more number of requests.I have started running in Non-GUI mode it's giving the result in summary format.I want to see which API is success and failed as in GUI mode we are able to see in view results tree listener.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we get Jmeter results in non-GUI mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089082/how-can-we-get-jmeter-results-in-non-gui-mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can create JMeter Dashboard to see the results. Run the test in non gui mode as below: 
**jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan    -l /path/to/result.jtl** 
once your test is complete you can use (.jtl) file to generate dashboard
run the command as below: 
**jmeter -g  /path/to/result.jtl  -o OUTPUT_FOLDER**

Check the output folder  --> **index.html**, you will see the list of API requests you have sent.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) mode you should specify the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) where the test output will be stored like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
             ^test       ^file with
              plan        test results
```

Once your test is finished you can:

1. Open the `result.jtl` (it's a normal [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file) with [MS Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/excel) or [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) and analyze the results there
2. Open the `result.jtl` file with the [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice, i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)
3. Generate tables and/or charts you need using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)
4. Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard from the .jtl results file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only)